# Get tweet's user location only in english language

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, sentiment-analysis

I am doing sentiment analysis of twitter text and in this process also want to get user's location. But I only want the location in English language. Now when I am using getUser().getLocation(), it returns the location irrespective of the language. Is there any way to translate or set the location null if not in English?

Comment: If you add "lang:en" at the end of your search query, Twitter returns you only tweets in English. Maybe this helps. You can try this also on twitter web or mobile applications.